# Check if a label has visible property to true.c# winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, if-statement, visible

How to check if a label is visible?This is not working...

```
   if(labelFS.Visible = false)
        {do sth}
   else//labelFS.Visible = true
        {do other}
```

solved

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `==` to compare two values, not the assignment operator (a single `=`).

By using a single `=`, you're actually setting the value of `labelFS.Visible` to `False`, which hides it.

*(There's also no need to type out* `true` *and* `false` *.)*

```
if (labelFS.Visible)
    // do something
else
    // do something else
```

I'd suggest reading up on the difference. Here's a start...

- [Equality Operator (==)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53k8ybth.aspx)
- [Assignment Operator (=)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691314%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

```
if(labelFS.Visible == false)
        {do sth}
   else//labelFS.Visible == true
        {do other}
```

Use `==` instead of `=`